# HTML form with branch conditions not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a form where the user enters a value, checks a radio button and then clicks on the submit button. The user should get a response by an alert message in the following three cases.

Case 1: Expressed checked AND Product quantity is > 50 && < 500

Case 2: Expressed checked AND Product quantity is NOT > 50 && < 500

Case 3: Standard checked

Regardless of whatever value I enter, it goes straight to Case 2.
Case 1 and Case 3 are never reached.

**Code Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML form</title>
<script>
function calculate() {
        var productQuantity = document.getElementById("product-quantity").value +
            " Units";
        var express = document.getElementById("express");
        var standard = document.getElementById("standard");
        
        // EXPRESSED ------------------------------
        if (express.checked) {
            if ((productQuantity > 50) && (productQuantity < 500)) {
                    // CASE 1 
                    alert("your order of " + productQuantity +
                        " will be ready within two working day");
                } else {
                    // CASE 2
                    alert("sorry! your order is " + productQuantity +
                        " and it has to be over 50 in order to qualify for this service"
                    );
                }
            }
        // STANDARD ------------------------------
                else if (standard.checked) {
                // CASE 3
                alert("your order of " + productQuantity + 
                      " will be ready within seven working day");
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="product-quantity">Please Enter number of units
                    for this product:</label> <input class="form-control" id=
                    "product-quantity" placeholder="Product Quantity" type=
                    "number">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="product-time" style="padding-top:20px">
            <label for="title">Production Time</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <input id="express" name="radio" type="radio"> <label for=
                    "productionTime">Express</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <input id="standard" name="radio" type="radio"> <label for=
                    "productionTime">Standard</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><span class="input-group-btn" style=
        "padding-top:25px"><button class="btn btn-default" id="button" onclick=
        "calculate()" type="button"><span class="input-group-btn" style=
        "padding-top:25px">Submit!</span></button></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: then, what is the issue here?

Comment: @Aparna the issue here when i choose express option it should alert the value based on the condition rather than going to else even if it does not meet the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

productQuantity is a string, comparing it to an integer in your if statement will always be false.  I would recommend converting it to an integer before your if statement, then converting it back to a string and adding the ' Units' part.

```
var productQuantity = document.getElementById("product-quantity").value
var productQuantityInt = parseInt(productQuantity, 10);
if (productQuantityInt > 50 && productQuantityInt < 500){...};
productQuantity += ' Units';
```

Hope that helps

Edit (oops):

Since the productQuantity input field is set as a 'number' type, you don't need a lot of my code.  This should work:

```
var productQuantity = document.getElementById("product-quantity").value
if (productQuantity > 50 && productQuantity < 500){...};
productQuantity += ' Units';
```

Comment: it certainly fixed the issue, but can i ask how is it the productQuantity was a string when i gave the input value as numbers shouldn't be an integer? sorry if it was a newbie question and thanks for your help

Comment: oops, I actually didn't notice you had the input type set as 'number' - so the second line of my code (the productQuantityInt variable) can be completely removed.  What's happening is you're adding a number to a string when you add + ' Units', which in javascript will convert the entire thing to a string.  I'll edit my answer to reflect what I mean

Comment: I see, so the problem was with adding the + units that made it as string rather than an integer, what a silly mistake hahaha thanks man